# Setting user kwargs as field vales in Django Form with Class-based View

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms

I have a Django application (1.11) to track referrals (referred by a user). I want to pass the id of the authenticated user to the ModelForm 'referrer' field (and since it's from the current logged in user the field shouldn't be editable).

```
class Referral(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    referrer = models.ForeignKey('users.User', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='referrals', null=True, blank=True)
```

View:

```
class ReferralFormView(FormView):

    form_class = ReferralForm
    template_name = "refer.html"
    success_url = reverse_lazy('thanks')

    def get(self, request):
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            return super(ReferralFormView, self).get(request)
        else:
            return redirect('login')

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        user = self.request.user
        form_kwargs = super(ReferralFormView, self).get_form_kwargs()
        form_kwargs['referrer'] = user.id
        return form_kwargs

    def form_valid(self,form):
        ...
        form.save()
        return super(ReferralFormView, self).form_valid(form)
```

I override `get_form_kwargs` in the view, then modify form **init**

```
class ReferralForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Referral

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
      referrer = kwargs.pop('referrer', None)
      super(ReferralForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
      self.fields['referrer'].disabled = True
      self.fields['referrer'].queryset = User.objects.filter(id=referrer)
```

However all I see is a blank referrer field, what am I missing to make the user the value of that field (which can't be edited)? I also tried `self.fields['referrer'].initial = User.objects.filter(id=referrer)`. I don't want the user to have to select their own username from a queryset of one.

[image]

I can print a `<QuerySet [<User: username>]>` for `user = User.objects.filter(id=referrer)`, so why isn't it setting that user as the field value?

Update: I can assign the user value with

```
self.fields['referrer'].initial = User.objects.filter(id=referrer).first()
self.fields['referrer'].disabled = True
```

However, on form submit Referral obj is not saving with the referrer field value (that value's still blank)

thanks

Answer (score 0):

what I needed to do was select the user obj in the queryset:

```
    self.fields['referrer'].initial = User.objects.filter(id=referrer).first()
```

but using `self.fields['referrer'].disabled = True` disabled the field so I was still getting a blank value on submit (disabled doesn't do what the docs say it does). Using `self.fields['referrer'].initial = User.objects.filter(id=referrer).first()` with that field set as readonly allows the form to submit with the initial value